# vb.net application and microsoft access database deployment

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have developed an application using VB.NET and used microsoft access as the database back end.

Deployment reqiurements : The application is to be deployed on a LAN with 5_15 machines. Any user profile can be accessed from any machine. Any changes to the database entries should be reflected on all machines.

I am confused about how I should achieve this deployment. According to my research :

1.The database should be deployed on one machine . This machine will acts as the database server .

My problem(s) : I am familiar with accessing databases on local machine but how to access a remote database?. How will the connection string look like? Do I need to install ms access on all machines or only on the server machine ? Do I have to deal with concurrency issues (multiple users accessing/modifying same data simultaneously) or is it handled by the database engine?

2.The application can be deployed in 2 ways : i. Storing the executable on a shared network drive on the server.Providing shortcut on desktop of each machine. ii. Storing the executable itself on each machine.

My Problem(s) : How does approach 1 work ? (One instance of an executable running on multiple machines ? :s) In approach 2 , will the changes in database entries be reflected on all machines appropriately? In approach 2, if there are changes to the application , is there any method to update it on all machines ? ( Other than redeploying it on each machine ) Which approach is preferable? Do I need to install the .NET framework all machines? How will i set the connection string to be able to access the database in the network?

Will I have to make any other system changes ( firewall,security,permissions) ? If given a choice to install the operating system on each machine ,which version of windows is preferable for such an application environment ?

This is my first time deploying a multi-user database application on a network.I'll be very grateful for any suggestions/advice,references,etc.

Comment: Windows application or Web application

Comment: Windows application - SenthilKumar

Comment: I suggest to split your question in more small questions. As it is now it is to broad to answer without writing a book or a blog article on deployment scenarios with MS-Access

Comment: \\systemname\sharingdrive\sharefoldername Ex: \\Sys1\d\data\db.mdb

Comment: Steve- Firstly before i deploy my vb.net application how will i write the connection string?am using ms access as my database

Comment: i didnt get u SenthilKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try and answer your questions:

Yes you should deploy the database onto a central machine. (Although Access *may* not the best choice for this sort of thing see: [Is MS Access (JET) suitable for multiuser access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763888/is-ms-access-jet-suitable-for-multiuser-access))

For connection strings look at this site: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

For deployment of your executable you should [look at clickonce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This simplifies the install and upgrade of your application significantly. A small learning curve now will reduce your administration headache later.