# How to use MDB database with multiple processes

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

I have Microsoft Access Database (MDB file) and i would want to use it from two processes/apps (selecting, inserting, deleting data) By im keep getting an error that file is already used by this user on this pc.

Is it even possible to do that? To have 2 connections with read/write rights?

Comment: Try to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763888/is-ms-access-jet-suitable-for-multiuser-access

Comment: Be sure that the two user/apps have the right permissions on the folder where you keep the database, but more important, do not keep the connection open. Always close and dispose after usage. Then good luck because Access is not a good solution when data sharing is required

Comment: Here the official doc on splitting MDB https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-an-access-database-3015ad18-a3a1-4e9c-a7f3-51b1d73498cc